# How to avoid virtual home button to be drawn on the top of my FireMonkey application?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

How to avoid the virtual semi-transparent home button drawn on top over my application when the Android device has no physical home button?

I'm developing an Android application in Delphi 10.1 Berlin version.

This is what i have :

[image]

And this is what i need :

[image]

NOTE: this is on all device. but it's also look like it's connected with

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
```

defined in `androidmanifest`. when i replace 23 by 14 (for example) then it's work ok (but i need 23 to have all the permission features of marshmallow)

Comment: Please add a screenshot

Comment: You will not see anything on the screenshoot because the virtual home button is drawed transparently, so it's drawed but you can't see it, but it's here because it's catch all click event

Comment: @loki you should add that information to your question.

Comment: screenshot added ...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set fullscreen to false on your form?

Please refer to [immersive mode](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html)

Comment: ok so maybe try to check this setting Project>Options>VersionInfo and property theme (should be TitleBar)